# Edits and Community Wikis

Tags: support, editing, community-wiki

How many times can I edit a question/answer before it automatically gets turned into a community wiki?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Automatic Community-wikification of very long answers with lots of edits](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1770/5363)

Answer (score 6):

Ten, if you are the owner. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741) on the SO meta.

Answer (score 3):

Not so long ago it was announced that posts will be [no longer automatically turned into CW](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/). So, unless the rule is changed again, there is no need to worry about this.

Comment: See also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16455/multiple-edits-and-community-wiki